# R - send two-line command to system

Tags: r, command, system

I am using a `ImageMagick` command on a OS X system to create a 2x2 panel consisting of four `.png` figures that I have on my disk:

```
convert \( image1.png image2.png -append \) \
\( image3.png image4.png -append \) +append result.png
```

When pasted to my terminal, the above command gets adjusted by the system, receiving a `>` to the beginning of the second line:

```
convert \( image1.png image2.png -append \) \
> \( image3.png image4.png -append \) +append result.png
```

The resulting figure looks like this:

[image]

I am trying to reproduce this last command from within R by using the following commands:

```
> line1 <- paste0(" convert \\(", " img1.png img2.png -append \\)", " \\")
> line2 <- paste0(" < \\(", " img3.png img4.png -append \\) ", "+append result.png")
> cat(paste(line1, line2, sep='\n'))
 convert \( img1.png img2.png -append \) \
 < \( img3.png img4.png -append \) +append result.png
```

Apparently, the result from `cat` is what I need, but I can't find the right way to send it to the system. I tried to combine it with `system`, but I get an error:

```
system(cat(paste(line1, line2, sep='\n')))
Error in system(cat(paste(line1, line2, sep = "\n"))) : 
  non-empty character argument expected
```

The question is: how can I use R to send that specific two-line command to the system?

Comment: *a.* You shouldn't need to run it as a separate line unless it's a second command, which you can pass in a second call. *b.* The `\ ` at the end of a shell line escapes the newline character (which gets ignored as extra whitespace), so if you _really_ want to pass it as such, just add a newline (`\n`) instead, e.g. `system('echo $((2+ \n 3))')`. *c.* [The `magick` package](https://ropensci.org/tutorials/magick_tutorial.html) makes this all somewhat unnecessary. *d.* The best way to solve this is to plot them on a grid in the first place with `mfrow` or the like.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @alistaire. Any particular tip regarding the `magick` package? I installed it but the only thing I managed to do was to combine the figures in a row... Couldn't find documentation to assist me create a `m x n` panel...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments to this question, I ended up finding the answer. This is the code I used from within R:

```
system(paste0("convert \\( img1.png img2.png -append \\) \\( img3.png img4.png -append \\) +append result.png"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the [magick](https://ropensci.org/tutorials/magick_tutorial.html) package and making a reproducible example, it might look like

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(magick)

# make and same sample images
seq(4) %>%
    map(~data_frame(x = seq(.x))) %>% 
    walk(~{ggplot(.x, aes(x, x)) + geom_point(); ggsave(paste0('plot', max(.x), '.svg'))})

# read images
images <- image_read(paste0('plot', seq(4), '.svg'))

# join pairs of images horizontally, then join the pairs vertically
joined <- image_join(image_append(images[1:2]), 
                     image_append(images[3:4])) %>% 
    image_append(stack = TRUE)

# set margins
m <- par('mar')
par(mar = rep(0, 4))

# show plot
plot(joined)
```

[image]

```r
# reset margins
par(mar = m)

# save plot
image_write(joined, 'plot1234.png', format = 'png')
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution. It is a tad slow, perhaps because my `.png` files are high-res, but it works fine for my question.

Answer (score 1):

In your ImageMagick command remove the new line \ at the end of the first line and make the command just one long command on a single line as follows:

```
convert \( image1.png image2.png -append \) \( image3.png image4.png -append \) +append result.png
```

That should avoid the > prompt and allow your command to pass onward without getting confused by the > prompt